# how to use font name with menue items in kivymd?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

i am trying to set the font for the Arabic language in kivymd for menu items in kivymd, I didn't find any solution for this after reviewing the docs well, so does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use my example code, for this code to work you must download a ttf font file that contains the Arabic language characters and save it into the same folder where you're executing the code below, I downloaded JannaLTBold.ttf:

Here is the code by jbsidis:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard

KV = '''
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        id: m5
        spacing: dp(10)
        #padding: dp(20)
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .55}
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .4}
            orientation: "vertical"
        ScrollView:
            id: rvvv9
            bar_color: [0,0,1,.5]
            bar_inactive_color: [1,1,1,0]
            bar_width: dp(5)
            BoxLayout:
                id: container
                padding: dp(10)
                spacing: dp(100)
                default_size: None, dp(75)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'

        


<NN>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        spacing: dp(30)
        OneLineListItem:
            markup: True
            text: "[font=JannaLTBold.ttf] jbsidis شخص في هذا العالم يسمى: جبسيديس"
        MDCard:
            size_hint: 1,None
            Image:
                source: "Photos/pro.jpg"

'''

class NN(MDCard):
    pass

class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(20):
            self.root.ids.container.add_widget(
                NN()
            )

Test().run()
```

The result should be like the image:
jbsidis

[image]

Comment: thanks so much, this is helpful, and i will use the droidkofi.ttf , i think it's good, anyway thanks for the answer